# Security Exception in WCF service on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: wcf, security

I am having a problem hosting a simple WCF service in Windows 2003 Server. I am using the netTcpBinding and, by default, it is using Windows authentication.

The client is running on another server, and is called by a windows system process to pass some simple information back to the service.  The security context *should* be be passed through back to the service, and the client Identity should be NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

All this works just grand on Windows 2008 Server (and windows 7 FWIW). However, this same configuration fails on Windows 2003 Server R2, SP 2. I turned in WCF tracing and saw this exception on the service side:

SecurityTokenValidationException: The service does not allow you to log on anonymously

So it looks like on Windows 2003, the security context is not being passed through.

I have found some similar issues talked about in SO and this from MS Support, but it seems most of them revolve around IIS issues; this service is self-hosted in a windows service, no IIS involved.

EDIT: Just found out that this is a problem **ONLY** when the client is called by the windows system process. I can run the service client interactively (it is just a console application) and it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Here is the host WCF configuration:

```
<service name="MyService">
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="" 
        contract="IMyService">
        <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://TheAppServer:8732/MyService/" />
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>
```

and here is the client config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding 
            name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" 
            transactionFlow="false" 
            transferMode="Buffered" 
            transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" 
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard">
            <reliableSession 
                ordered="true" 
                inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" 
                enabled="false"/>
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport 
                    clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                    protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
                <message 
                    clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint 
        address="net.tcp://TheAppServer:8732/MyService/" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" 
        contract="IMyService" 
        name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
        <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: I believe you need to re-create the same binding configuration on the server side, and make sure the endpoint on the server side is using that binding configuration (with the transport security)

Comment: You may create the same binding on the server side, and according to the exception you list, I think the client didn't send the credentials to the server side, can you check this?

Comment: Just added an important edit: this configuration works just fine if I execute the client interactively from the desktop

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can host net.tcp in windows 2003